# How to calculate the hours and days between two dates/times?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to calculate the hours and days between two dates/times. I'm currently using `=(B1-A1)*24`

This works most of the time but occasionally my result is greater than 24. In those cases I would rather see the number in days, e.g. (3.5).

For example, I would like to use the formula `=(B1-A1)` if the result is greater than 24 hours and `=(B1-A1)*24` if the result is less than 24.

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Use the IF Function

The [IF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) function returns one value if a logical expression is `TRUE` and another if it is `FALSE`.
**Syntax**: `IF(logical_expression, value_if_true, value_if_false)`

##### Example Formula

```
# bare formula

=IF(B1-A1>1,
    B1-A1,
   (B1-A1)*24)


# rounding and labeling added

=IF(B1-A1>1,
    ROUND(B1-A1,1)& " days",
    ROUND((B1-A1)*24,2)&" hrs. ")
```

[image]